# QueryOver - add restriction on primitive collection

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

Given the following entity-

```
public class Friend
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<string> Nicknames { get; set; }
}
```

which is mapped like so:

```
mapping.HasMany(x => x.Nicknames).Element("Value")  //this gets auto-mapped to a different 'Nicknames' table
```

given a string, I want to retrieve friend who's name or one of his nicknames matches that string.
I can't figure out how to do that.. here's what I've got so far:

```
.Where(Restrictions.Or(
                    Restrictions.On<Friend>(f => f.Name).IsInsensitiveLike(name),
                    Restrictions.On<Friend>(f => f.Nicknames) // i'd like to be able to do: .Contains(name)   
                     )
                     ).List();
```

Comment: are nicknames on another table ? or same one ? show map please

Comment: @Chen- added info to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out that this is a known issue in nHib (and in fact, in Hibernate as well).
see [here](http://groups.google.com/group/nhusers/browse_frm/thread/dfe7ff130a86ebce/7f94d484a4aeaed5?lnk=gst&q=queryover%20collection%20string#7f94d484a4aeaed5).
I ended up using the Query API for this one.