# How to QueryOver a list of string in NHibernate

Tags: sql, nhibernate, queryover

I have a User model with below string list -

```
    private ISet<String> _mobileNumbers;

    public virtual ISet<String> MobileNumbers
    {
        get { return _mobileNumbers ?? (_mobileNumbers = new HashedSet<String>()); }
        set { _mobileNumbers = value; }
    }
```

I need to write a NHibernate QueryOver on this table to get a list of Users having a specific mobile number. Something like -

```
String mobileNumber = null;
Repository.QueryOver<User>()
            .JoinAlias(u => u.MobileNumbers, () => mobileNumber)
            .WhereRestrictionOn(() => mobileNumber)
                .IsLike(searchedMobileNumber, MatchMode.Exact);
```

I have thought of creating a Model for MobileNumber, or writing an SQL query which would do the same thing. But is there any other alternative??

Comment: Have you tested it? Does it works? Sadly defining mappings without an explicit entity is much simpler for writing the mapping, but much more complex for writing the queries.

Comment: No, it's not working. It give null pointer exception. :(

Comment: I've done some tests... While in HQL it is possible to do it (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/23152387/613130), in QueryOver I don't think it is possible. Probably a missing feature.

Comment: Should work in a LINQ query to retain type safety (compared to HQL).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not supported in *NHibernate QueryOver*: see for example [QueryOver - add restriction on primitive collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6440055/queryover-add-restriction-on-primitive-collection) .

It is supported in "pure" HQL queries, as written for example in https://stackoverflow.com/a/23152387/613130 .

Comment: Thanks. I ended up creating a Model for mobileNumber. Works fine.